# what else can i do to try and solve repeating letters on MBP

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

so i have a 2019 16" MBP on Catalina 10.15.7 and have had intermittent repeating letters.  a number of months ago i took it to an apple authorized center and they wiped it and installed a new keyboard.  I thought the issue was solved but recently it has returned.  I have disabled repeating letters in keyboard preferences to see if that made a difference and it doesent.  I's and sometimes S's repeat. I also have bluetoothed an older apple keyboard from my 2011 imac and i still get the repeating letters when using that.   Varies as to which letters.  I have also run the Apple hardware diagnostic test by restarting the MPB and holding the D key down.  No hardware issues.  Is there anything elase i can do to try and solve the issue so as not to have to send it back in?  Anything else to check?